# Very confused about pulse-echo measurements

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, waves, frequency, wavelength

[image]

Heres a link to the question im referring to just in case the image is not visible in the post - https://ibb.co/2vsZy90

Can someone please this mark scheme answer in simple terms. Firstly, what exactly is a pulse and how it is different from a normal wave?

Also, what is pulse duration and pulse length, and how exactly do they affect the detail carried by reflected signals? I don't understand this at all! Please explain in simple terms, as for my syllabus I don't need to know all the complex advanced information.

Answer (score 0):

"Pulse" is a colloquial term for a waveform that resembles a square wave.

Consider the following diagram of a pulse train:

[image: Pulse Train]

**Frequency** is defined as $\frac{1}{T}$, where $T$ is the signal's period.

**The time intervals which separate the pulses** are the duration of the signal's "low" in one period, denoted by "Space" in the diagram.

**Pulse Duration / Width** is defined as the duration of the signal's "high" in one period.

A shorter pulse width allows the bat, or any radar system, to better distinguish between multiple targets that may be located close together. Also, it reduces the blurring or "smearing" of the reflected signal, which can occur when the pulse width is longer.